# A or The. Which is more used?

Tags: articles

Which is more used and proper than the other?

Happiness is ___ name of a feeling. (a/the)

previous line: 
Money can't give happiness.

Answer (score 3):

Use "a" when the thing you are talking about is one among many. Use "the" when it is the only one or when the context limits it to just one.

In this case, we are talking about the name for one particular feeling. In context we're only thinking of one name for this feeling, so you'd say "the". It is "the name" for this feeling.

If you were trying to say that there are many different names for this feeling, than you would say "a name". Like, "Happiness is a name for this feeling. Joy is another name." But even when there is more than one name for something, unless you're talking about the fact that there is more than one name, we usually talk about "the name" of something.